# Day trip to a coffee farm in Yunnan

Tags: china, yunnan

I'm planning to travel to Yunnan and would like to tour a coffee farm.

There are visits included in longer tours, e.g. [here](https://www.roastersguild.org/blog/2017/11/30/join-the-roasters-guild-for-an-exclusive-trip-to-yunnan-china) or [here](http://wondersofyunnan.com/tours/9-days-yunnan-culinary-adventure). However, I would like to book this as a day trip.

Are there farms in Yunnan that offer this to tourists? Would it be a good idea to contact the organizers of the longer tours, or maybe email the farms visited by those tours directly?

Comment: I hope you find what you're looking for, but please don't overlook visiting a tea garden.  Yunnan produces some of the world's best black tea.